# Duplicate Primary Key while doing latteral flattening in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: merge, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, primary-key

I am kind a new with working with arrays in SNOWFLAKE database.

I am trying to load data into dimension tables in **SNOWFLAKE** database using **merge** statement where the primary keys of those dimension tables are generated in the staging table itself using **nextval** and used in dimension tables. I was **fine** until this point.

Now in my scenario, I might have **arrays** (**having more than one value**) as below screenshot and when I use **latteral** **flatten** those arrays and merge them into my dimension, I get **duplicate primary key** (For eg. If I have two values in my array, then I get same primary key value twice).

Could someone pleas help me in how I can overcome this problem or should I **not** generate the primary key for dimension tables in staging table and do it in the dimension table itself

Screeenshot of dataset with array of values

[image]

Screenshot of my result after merge of the array using lateral flatten

[image]

Comment: Can you help us reproduce the case with some sample data?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

That's the purpose of FLATTEN function, if you have one row with ID 1, and data [v1, v2], then the result will be:

```
1 -> v1
1 -> v2
```

Example as below:

```
with t as (
    select 1 as id, parse_json('["v1", "v2"]') as data
)
select id, value::varchar 
from t, 
lateral flatten(input => data)
;

+----+----------------+
| ID | VALUE::VARCHAR |
|----+----------------|
|  1 | v1             |
|  1 | v2             |
+----+----------------+
```

I think you need to review what you want to achieve and FLATTEN might not what you are after.